Continually receive updates to extension service worker from a page's MutationObserver
I want to watch some text on the page. I would normally do this with MutationObserver. It's important that I receive every update to this text that would also make it to the user's eyes, and send it back to my service worker (who will send it to a Native Messaging application).
chrome.scripting states,

If the script evaluates to a promise, the browser will wait for the promise to settle and return the resulting value.

This doesn't include streaming/continual results. How do I receive continual results from a page to a service worker?

Use messaging. If updates are infrequent use sendMessage,  otherwise use ports.

I am not in a content script; chrome.scripting doesn't create a content script but rather a script that runs in the page's JS environment (as I specify world: "MAIN", because I need to access properties of Custom Elements). As far as I understand, chrome.runtime isn't available in these scripts.

You can use externally_connectable messaging in the article I've linked. Either sendMessage or ports. Note that your code is also called a content script by the documentation.
